# Bin packing - variants and quantities across a known number of unique boxes

Tags: algorithm, math, bin-packing

I have a head-scratcher which feels similar to a classic bin packing problem, but I can't pin it down. Any help appreciated...

Problem:

I have a set of products that are all the same size, but there are differently coloured variants and different requested quantities of each making up an order.

I am allowed to pack them in any combinations, but I can only have a stipulated number of boxes with different contents.

I can supply different quantities of each box. The optimal solution is the one which has the fewest number of products shipped *above* the requested quantity.

EXAMPLE:
4 products fit in a box, I'm allowed 2 types of box with different contents and I need to ship 100 * Red, 200 * Blue, 300 * Green, 400 * Yellow;

I can't pack 25 boxes of red, 50 boxes of blue, 75 boxes of green and 100 boxes of yellow because I'm only allowed 2 different unique contents of the boxes, and this would be 4.

Therefore optimal solution would be:

100 boxes of 1 * Red, 2 * Blue and 1 * Yellow

150 boxes of 2 * Green and 2 * Yellow

I've fulfilled all my quantities exactly in this example, so there is zero waste.

Let's say the order only requires 395 yellow; the above solution will waste 5 yellows, but there is no solution which wastes fewer. The solution with the fewest wasted products is the best.

Comment: Could you tell us the actual scale of problem parameters of interest to you?

Comment: Continuing @DavidEisenstat's question, are you looking for an optimal solution, or a "good enough" solution that is easier  to write\runs faster?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat order of magnitude is product variants upto 100s, quantities upto 1,000,000s, and boxes fitting 100s of products.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov that's a good question - if a solution could run fast and produce the optimal result, that's obviously preferable, but if it's not feasible, then something which would favour the more-likely-to-be-good solutions first, so that the routine could be stopped early and have a good chance of having found a very good solution.

Comment: And still only two types? or does that change too? Also, do we have to put the maximum number of products in each box, or can out a few less?

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov sorry, missed that one, I think types realistically tops out at about 10. You don't have to fill every box.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution:** Not an algorithmic answer.

Use brute force.

Given the types, you could (fairly) easily check how much waste you would get.

Since in each type you can have only 4 items, and there are only two types, the number of different options here is `(4^4)^2` (based on `x=number_of_colours`, `y=number_of_items_in_type` and `z=number_of_types`, we have `(x^y)^z`).

So why not check all 65536 options? Most of them are easily disqualified (every colour has to be represents at least once, etc.)

**EDIT:** Since the numbers of the real problem are far greater than the example, this answer is no longer relevant. I am leaving it here in case a better idea creeps up.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in the **EDIT** part

Comment: We must have hit return at roughly the same time!